# Autowire annotation is not working for different package

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2, autowired

I am using spring3,struts2 and hibernate3 together.I have a samplemanager.java file in com.top package and another test.java file in net.top package.In this  test.java file i tried to use the samplemanager.java using @Autowired.But it throws null pointer exception can any one tell me a solution for this.

Comment: If you show some code and config files, it would be much easier to diagnose your problem.  Otherwise we're just guessing at what could have happened.

Comment: provide your configuration details as well as stack trace to debug the issue

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the component scan in your application context file for both packages:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.top.*, net.top.*" />
```

Comment: thank you for your interest,but its not working.again the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Check if your samplemanager class is annotated and if you scan the classpath for annotated beans in your configuration file. If it is not annotated you must define the bean in the configuration file.